# Do I still need to use async/await in a then block in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, state, setstate

so I have this block, if I don't use async/await, it will not work. My question is that I know setState is asynchronous, but isn't `then` block will make sure `setWow`finish first before move on to the `console.log` part? Thanks!

```
      const [wow, setWow]=useState(null);  
      submitForm(payload)
      .then(async() => await setWow("djflajdlk"))// if I don't use async/await, it will not work
      .then(() => console.log(wow))
      .catch(err => alert(err.message))
  }
```

Comment: Where does the stray `}` come from? Nothing in the code you posted does alter the `wow` variable, so I highly doubt that using `async` will make a difference. It will always log the value that `useState(null)` returned.

Comment: I'd suggest you place the `console.log(wow)` after the `const [wow, setWow]=useState(null);` instead of inside the promise chain. If you really need to use the new value inside the promise chain, I'd suggest to use `submitForm(payload).then(result => { setWow(result); console.log(result); }).catch(console.error);` instead of referring to `wow`.

Comment: @Bergi the `}` is a mistake sorry...But isn't the `setWow` is changing the value of `wow`?

Comment: No, it's changing the state, which causes React to render the component again, and in that function call `wow` will have a new value. It should be clear from `const wow = …` that it won't change.

Answer (score 2):

`setWow` in indeed async but it doesn't return a promise so you can't `await` it.

You can use a `useEffect` hook to detect changes in your state and perform a side effect, e.g.:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // wow has changed, do something with wow
   console.log(wow)
}, [wow])
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to set WOW in my `submitForm` function and do something with the `wow`. Can `useEffect` do that or it just listens for `wow` change?

Comment: `useEffect` will only detect the change in `wow`. You could split your logic into two parts - one in the effect, the other in the promise chain - or do as @Bergi suggested above

Comment: It may be hard to separate my logic, so I will prefer Bergi's solution but your solution might work for my another problem, thank you!